# kexec doesn't unmount root filesystem

Tags: kexec

With a Debian Jessie 8.0, freshly installed (with systemd), I installed kexec.

When I restart the computer with the `reboot` command, this invoke kexec.
The reboot is ok but I have a message into the logs:
`systemd-fsck[xxx]: /dev/sda1 file system not cleanly unmounted, check forced`
The next line indicate that no error where found in the filesystem.

I seldom use kexec, so I'm don't know if this error is normal. If found nothing with Google.

Anyone know if this error is normal or not ? If not, how to avoid it ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in systemd ( or rather its units/scripts ) which you should report to debian.  It should be remounting the filesystem read-only as the last thing that happens before the call to `kexec`, which would prevent this from happening.